# Import from excel to sql when 1st column has headers

Tags: sql-server

I want to import an excel file in sql server 2014 where my first column contains column names. So data is in columns instead of rows.

Please let me know the best way to import this in sql server so that in sql table my first row will have column names and data will be in consecutive rows.

[image: Excel image]

[image: SQL Image]

Comment: Please post an example of the data, and indicate what you've tried

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid - I have attched screenshots of both excel file and sql table. I used SSMS Import export wizard to import in sql.

Comment: Personally, I would load the data into a staging table first (using SSIS for example), then transform your data on SQL Server by method of a cross pivot.

Comment: Would be easier to have Excel columns match database table columns. You can select all cells in Excel, then do Copy, then Paste Transpose in Excel to achieve that.

Comment: @PeterB I havemultiple excel files (around 100) so don't wan tto do it in excel. Instead want some method to import it transposed in sql server.

Comment: hi @Larnu Please could you explain me method of cross pivot?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: So this excel file might have any number of columns depending on how many rows there are. This is a bad format for inserting into SQL Server. Are you sure it has to be that way?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes thats how my source data is going to be.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks a lot. I will look into this link.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to do that once, select all the cells in Excel without headers and paste into SQL Management Studio with the table in edit mode.
2. If this is a regular task, you can create a SSMS package or a Stored Procedure (insert + openrowset)

   ```
   create procedure [dbo].LoadData
   (
           @file nvarchar(200)=null
   )
   as
   begin
           declare @sql varchar(max)
           set @sql='INSERT INTO DBO.Table
           (
                   column1, column2
           )
           select column1
                                   ,column2
           from openrowset(bulk N''' + @file +''',
            formatfile = N''d:\xml\Table.xml'') as t1'

            print @sql
            exec (@sql)
   end


   --- Table.xml

   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
     <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
     <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
     <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="column1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
     <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="column2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    </ROW>
   </BCPFORMAT>
   ```

Comment: Hi @vicosanz  Thanks for your reply.  Yes its a regular task. I have to import multiple excels in the same table daily.  Do you mind explaining a bit more about what are we doing in this stored procedure? Apologies but i am bit new to SQL.

Comment: Hello, the Stored Procedure dbo.LoadData needs one parameter with the full path of the CSV file. You need to save the Excel files in CSV format and execute the stored procedure like this: EXEC dbo.LoadData 'c:\data\file1.csv'... If you need to do that as a scheduled task you need to create a tiny program in c# that read the list of files in a specific folder and execute the stored procedure for each file.